# brace expansion in process substitution?

Tags: bash

I'd like to compare the output of one program on two files. It would be something like:

`comm -23 <(cat a/somefile) <(cat b/somefile)`

Where `cat` is a stand in for a monster of a command.

Here's what I know. If I do `echo {a,b}/somefile` then I get

`a/somefile b/somefile`

which is correct.

I tried to apply this "explosion" to the process substitution: `comm -23 <(cat {a,b}/somefile)` needless to say I got an error `comm: missing operand after ‘/proc/self/fd/16’`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) is the term.

Comment: With the infamous all time favorite [eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)  something like `eval comm -23 "<(sort "{a,b}"/somefile)"`

Comment: `eval` ? https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7v6Dh3c1FW4/VplPvz_ZQBI/AAAAAAAACgQ/X42IJ3P0kuo/s1600/cross.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{a,b}` syntax is a form of [brace expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), but its scope is limited. It won't repeat everything to the left of it:

```
$ echo cat {a,b}/somefile
cat a/somefile b/somefile
```

However, if the there's anything "touching" the left brace:

```
$ echo cat{a,b}/somefile
cata/somefile catb/somefile
```

Going back to your example, the `<(cat {a,b}/somefile)` part expands to `<(cat a/somefile b/somefile)`, which will just concatenate the contents of the two files and put them into the temp file created by the process substitution. But `comm` expects two arguments, not one, which is why you're getting the error. You knew this, but I guess you had different expectations about how brace expansion behaves (the scope up to which it extends).

I suggest you just create your own function with that "monster of a command" and reuse it in two process substitutions:

```sh
monster() {
  cat "$@"
}

comm -23 <(monster a/somefile) <(monster b/somefile)
```